# Looking for a formula for automatic member placement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

Chart 2

[image: Chart 2]

Chart 1

[image: Chart 1]

Chart 1b

[image: Chart 1b]

I have a group page, and to keep track of my members' presence/absence, I created this.

In chart 1, I manually have to write who's active/inactive. They have to be minimum 4 days active a week, to be in the active column.

Is there a way, to link my chart 2, to chart 1, so when I work on chart 2, of member activity, they will automatically be placed either under active or inactive Column?

I thought about using the `COUNTIF` formula, but what I don't understand is, how can I make it auto-place? By that I mean, when a member is 4 days active a week, I want them to be placed under Active column. If they're active below 4 days a week, I want them to automatically be placed under Inactive column, show in chart 1.

I also don't want my auto sum to be disturbed shown in chart 1b

Hope someone got a solution, thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Typically, you don't "place" a value in a selected column based on a condition.  Each column would contain a formula that tests the condition for that column.  If it passes, it displays the result you want there, otherwise it displays a blank.

Comment: I didn't know how else I can explain what I'm trying to do. But here are the keypoints: Member name - active days (4 days per week minimum) - If active 4 days, will be placed under active Column, and the Inactive side would be blank. If below 4 days a week, will be placed under inactive Column, and active side would be blank. That's at least what I want to do, so I don't manually have to write ''1'' in columns as you can see in the screenshot.

Comment: Use an IF test in each result column to assess the conditions.  If the conditions meet the requirements for a "1", make the result "1".  If not, you can make it display as blank by returning a "null", which is two double-quote marks with nothing between them (an empty text string: "").  Give it a try and update your question with any specific problem you run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this formula:

**=if(number of cell>=15,"1",if(number of the cell<=14,"").**

15 = half of a month

And the other way around.

Comment: Good start.  It isn't clear whether you solved it and made some typos transcribing your solution, or this is an unsuccessful attempt.  If it's the latter, and you are still looking for help, move this to your question.

Comment: You're on the right track, but the formula needs some tweaking.  The structure is `IF(condition, true result, false result)`.  You need a comma between `15` and `"1"`.  You don't need to nest another IF because that's already the false condition, just put the null there.  But if you do nest another IF as the false result, that needs to be a complete IF structure; you would need to add a false result and another close parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it managed to work! I added another ''if'' because when the value is below 14, I don't want the formula to write anything on the active side. I wanted it completely blank.